# Access ItemsControl Items and Animate One by One

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

Today is a good day since I started with WPF, this for a launcher I'm creating.
Using the following code, I managed to get the result to be seen in the screenshot:

```
<Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Programs}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Text}" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" Width="128" Height="150" >
                        <Button.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Button.RenderTransform>
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Height="128" />
                                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,10" />
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                        <Button.Resources>
                            <Storyboard SpeedRatio="4" x:Key="MouseEnterStoryboard" x:Name="MouseEnterStoryboard">
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#22FFFFFF"></ColorAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard SpeedRatio="4" x:Key="MouseLeaveStoryboard" x:Name="MouseLeaveStoryboard">
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Transparent"></ColorAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard Duration="00:00:00.05" x:Key="MouseClickStoryboard" AutoReverse="True">
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="0.8" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="WindowLoadedStoryboard">
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="00:00:01" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </Button.Resources>
                        <Button.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseEnterStoryboard}" />
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseLeaveStoryboard}" />
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseClickStoryboard}" />
                            </EventTrigger>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
                                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource WindowLoadedStoryboard}"></BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Button.Triggers>
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Now, for each item in the list bound to this control, it will create a button.
How would I access this button programmatically, better yet, how would I access one of the Storyboards programatically since assigning a name (x:to them simply won't do the trick it seems...

Also, how can I animate the buttons one by one? Currently they each fade in at exact the same time (@ WindowLoadedStoryboard), but I would like to let each button fade in one by one with a short delay, to create a nice effect. How would I achieve this?

Hope someone can answer these 2 questions for me!

Greetings!

Comment: Did anyone see this question?

Comment: Please do not ask such questions here... you can see that people *have* seen your question by looking at the part of this page (top right) that shows the page view statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem with accessing the elements defined in the `DataTemplate` is caused because you defined those elements in a `DataTemplate`... those elements could be rendered in many different types of UI container controls. You can find the solution in the [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page from MSDN.

You first need to get hold of the relevant container control that contains the item that has had that `DataTemplate` applied to it. Next, you need to get the `ContentPresenter` from that container control and then you can get the `DataTemplate` from `ContentPresenter`. Finally, you can access the named elements from the `DataTemplate`. From the linked page:

```
// Getting the currently selected ListBoxItem 
// Note that the ListBox must have 
// IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem set to True for this to work
ListBoxItem myListBoxItem = (ListBoxItem)(myListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.
    ContainerFromItem(myListBox.Items.CurrentItem));

// Getting the ContentPresenter of myListBoxItem
ContentPresenter myContentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBoxItem);

// Finding textBlock from the DataTemplate that is set on that ContentPresenter
DataTemplate myDataTemplate = myContentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
TextBlock myTextBlock = 
    (TextBlock)myDataTemplate.FindName("textBlock", myContentPresenter);

// Do something to the DataTemplate-generated TextBlock
MessageBox.Show("The text of the TextBlock of the selected list item: " + 
    myTextBlock.Text);
```