# Scrollview for Itemscontrol grid

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview, itemscontrol

I have a custom control which is basically an itemscontrol.
It's a grid of 3x3 buttons and I want a scrollview to have different pages with every page having 3x3 buttons.

Below are some images to illustrate what I mean:

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/2reiez6.png]

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/69kwhl.png]

[image: http://i61.tinypic.com/1z4cr6d.png]

How would I create something like this?|
The full code of my control can be found here:
[Access ItemsControl Items and Animate One by One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367856/access-itemscontrol-items-and-animate-one-by-one?noredirect=1#comment32246377_21367856)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a ScrollViewer inside your Grid and have your 3x3 Grid in a horizontally oriented StackPanel.

```
<Grid >
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="stack">
                  ...
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
```

Then use ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged to change the scroll offset

```
private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int direction = e.HorizontalChange > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        (sender as ScrollViewer).ScrollToHorizontalOffset(stack.ActualWidth * direction / [number of grids]);

    }
```

Comment: Very late, but I just saw my question again and this is indeed how I implemented it back then!